# Is this the right strategy for Cloud Functions (Gen 2) for API requests?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to build GCP Cloud Functions which are triggered via Cloud Scheduler to collect odds data from bookmakers API's for a variety of different sports and competitions that run on different schedules.

I am looking for some advice on my approach about if it is the right strategy or if there is a better way to achieve what I want.

I have been using python for the code and GCP Cloud Functions (Gen 2), Cloud Scheduler, Pub/Sub. Firestore.

**Objective:** To use collect odds data from bookmakers API feeds and store desired data points from the feeds in Firestore.

**Plan:** Setup Cloud Functions (Gen 2) with Cloud Scheduler to collect the odds data for each sports competition which runs on a range of different schedules.

**Problem:** Each sport will have 3-5 betting markets collected for each event. Sometimes the bookmaker API feed requires that you make one API call to get event Ids, then another call using those event ids in the API URL to get the events odds data. So there are 3-5 API calls to collect all the required betting market data for each game.

At the moment I have those different API calls set up as different functions and it seems to work all ok when I run it locally.

Approach: I would like to set up each of those functions on Cloud Functions (Gen 2) using a One to Many PubSub Messaging System.

- **Function 1** (event id collection - sends event ids to pubsub topic)
- **Function 2** (odds market 1 collection using event ids from pubsub message of which this function is a subscriber)
- **Function 3** (odds market 2 collection using event ids from pubsub message of which this function is a subscriber)

I would need function 1 to run first (cloud scheduler), collect the data and push to pubsub, then once that message is in pubsub I would need functions 1 and 2 to run once the message is in pubsub and pulled to function.

This is the code for Function 1 which collected the event id's for the games:

```
import requests
import json
from firebase_admin import firestore
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

db = firestore.Client(project='xxxxxxx')

# API INFO
Base_url = 'https://xxxxxxx.net/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2'
Sport_id = '1000093204'
AppID = 'xxxxxxx'
AppKey = 'xxxxxxx'
Country = 'en_AU'
Site = 'xxxxxxx'


project_id = "xxxxxxx"
topic_id = "xxxxxxx_basketball_nba"


publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
# The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
# in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_id}`
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)



def win_odds(request):

    event_ids = []

    url = f"{Base_url}/betoffer/event/{','.join(map(str, event_ids))}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}"
    print(url)

    windata = requests.get(url).text
    windata = json.loads(windata)

    for odds_data in windata['betOffers']:
        if odds_data['betOfferType']['name'] == 'Head to Head' and 'MAIN' in odds_data['tags']:
            event_id = odds_data['eventId']
            home_team = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['participant']
            home_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['odds']
            away_team = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['participant']
            away_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['odds']

            print(f'{event_id} {home_team} {home_team_win_odds} {away_team} {away_team_win_odds}')

            event_ids.append(event_id)

            # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'xxxxxxx_au').document(u'basketball_nba').collection(u'win_odds').document(
                f'{event_id}')
            doc_ref.set({
                u'event_id': event_id,
                u'home_team': home_team,
                u'home_team_win_odds': home_team_win_odds,
                u'away_team': away_team,
                u'away_team_win_odds': away_team_win_odds,
                u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
            })

    return event_ids


print(f"Published messages to {topic_path}.")
```

Below is the code for the functions that will pull the event ids from pubsub and use in their API calls to collect the data on each betting market.

Below is the template for the subscriber functions which will pull the event ids message from pubsub subscription and then use those event ids in the API call for that function.

```
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import requests
import json
from firebase_admin import firestore
import functions_framework


db = firestore.Client(project='xxxxxxx')

# API INFO
Base_url = 'https://xxxxxxx.net/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2'
Sport_id = '1000093204'
AppID = 'xxxxxxx'
AppKey = 'xxxxxxx'
Country = 'en_AU'
Site = 'xxxxxxx'

project_id = "xxxxxxx"
subscription_id = "xxxxxxx_basketball_nba_events"
timeout = 5.0

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)

@functions_framework.cloud_event
def win_odds(message):
    print(message.data)

    event_ids = json.loads(message.data)

    url = f"{Base_url}/betoffer/event/{','.join(map(str, event_ids))}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}"
    print(url)

    windata = requests.get(url).text
    windata = json.loads(windata)

    for odds_data in windata['betOffers']:
        if odds_data['betOfferType']['name'] == 'Head to Head' and 'MAIN' in odds_data['tags']:
            event_id = odds_data['eventId']
            home_team = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['participant']
            home_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['odds']
            away_team = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['participant']
            away_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['odds']

            print(f'{event_id} {home_team} {home_team_win_odds} {away_team} {away_team_win_odds}')

            # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'xxxxxxx_au').document(u'basketball_nba').collection(u'win_odds').document(
                f'{event_id}')
            doc_ref.set({
                u'event_id': event_id,
                u'home_team': home_team,
                u'home_team_win_odds': home_team_win_odds,
                u'away_team': away_team,
                u'away_team_win_odds': away_team_win_odds,
                u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
            })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=win_odds)
    print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

    # Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
    with subscriber:
        try:
            # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
            # unless an exception is encountered first.
            streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
            streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.

    print("Listening, then shutting down.")
```

Comment: How long it take to request 1 odds market for 1 event ID? And how many event ID do you have? Will this number increase?

Comment: request 1 is very quick, under 1sec. The event Ids are in pubsub quickly also. The amount of event Ids varies day to day and sport to sport. But usally, not more then 20.

Comment: My question is: Scaling pattern with PubSub and several functions is great, and correct. But are you sure that is not overkill if under 3 minutes you get all the events, all the odds and store the result in your database?

Comment: what solution would you recommend?

Comment: Depends on the total duration and the growth expectation. If it's fast (less than 10 minutes) and won't grow, you can do all the stuff in the same function.

Comment: can you please point me in the direction of an example function with multiple API calls using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249462/discussion-between-drews-and-guillaume-blaquiere).

Comment: DrewS, do let me know if the below recommendations were useful.

Comment: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable - getting this error with function 2 when setup.

Comment: As per the error it seems that you are not able to listen on port 8080 and or there is a mismatch on the container port and listener,you can try to listen on whatever is in the PORT environment variable and match these.
Check this link for further help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945278/why-cloud-run-showing-listen-on-this-port-error

Comment: im strugging to find out a how to set the port correctly. Where would I  change this setting?

Comment: I have provided an answer to your new posted question regarding this.Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541847/how-to-fix-missing-port-issue-with-gcp-cloud-function-gen2-when-deployed/74548085#74548085

Answer (score 0):

The above could be achieved by performing asynchronous calls as PubSub.    For this you have to:

- Create a PubSub topic
- Deploy the Cloud Function 2[CF2] with a trigger on PubSub event on
  the previously created topic
- Deploy the Cloud function 3[CF3] with a trigger on PubSub event on
  the previously created topic
- Function Cloud function 1[CF1]creates a PubSub message with publish
  it.
- Function CF2 and CF3 are triggered in parallel with the message
  published in the PubSub. They extract the parameters from it and do
  the process.
- If CF2 and CF3 exist and are triggered by HTTP call, you can set up a
  HTTP push subscription on PubSub Topic.

If you need to do asynchronous requests and you are using Python you can try with [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) libraries, there is one [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755996/can-or-how-to-use-python-asyncio-on-google-cloud-functions).
Also, you can check [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#triggering_the_function) or [Cloud Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub).

Comment: `The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable` - getting this error with function 2 when setup. Seems to receive the pubsub message though.