# How to fix missing port issue with GCP Cloud Function (Gen2) when deployed?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a cloud function (gen2) in GCP but running into the same issue and get this error with each deploy when Cloud Functions sets up Cloud Run:

> The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.

**MAIN.PY**

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.cloud import firestore
import requests
import json
from firebase_admin import firestore
import google.auth

credentials, project = google.auth.default()



# API INFO
Base_url = 'https://xxxxxxxx.net/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2'
Sport_id = 'xxxxxxxx'
AppID = 'xxxxxxxx'
AppKey = 'xxxxxxxx'
Country = 'en_AU'
Site = 'www.xxxxxxxx.com'


project_id = "xxxxxxxx"
subscription_id = "xxxxxxxx-basketball-nba-events"
timeout = 5.0

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)


db = firestore.Client(project='xxxxxxxx')

def winodds(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:

        events = json.loads(message.data)
        event_ids = events['event_ids']

        url = f"{Base_url}/betoffer/event/{','.join(map(str, event_ids))}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}"
        print(url)

        windata = requests.get(url).text
        windata = json.loads(windata)

        for odds_data in windata['betOffers']:
            if odds_data['betOfferType']['name'] == 'Head to Head' and 'MAIN' in odds_data['tags']:
                event_id = odds_data['eventId']
                home_team = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['participant']
                home_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['odds']
                away_team = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['participant']
                away_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['odds']

                print(f'{event_id} {home_team} {home_team_win_odds} {away_team} {away_team_win_odds}')

                # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
                doc_ref = db.collection(u'xxxxxxxx').document(u'basketball_nba').collection(u'win_odds').document(f'{event_id}')
                doc_ref.set({
                    u'event_id': event_id,
                    u'home_team': home_team,
                    u'home_team_win_odds': home_team_win_odds,
                    u'away_team': away_team,
                    u'away_team_win_odds': away_team_win_odds,
                    u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
                })

streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=winodds)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

# Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
with subscriber:
    try:
        # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
        # unless an exception is encountered first.
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    winodds()
```

**DOCKER FILE**

```
# Use the official Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.10

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . .


ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS /app/xxxxx-key.json

ENV PORT 8080


# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install functions-framework
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD exec functions-framework --target=winodds --debug --port=$PORT
```

I am using PyCharm and it all seems to work locally when I run via Docker, Main.py, and Cloud Run locally. But as soon as I deploy I get an error straight away.

Please can someone point me in the right direction? Where do I need to edit the ports # so my cloud function will deploy successfully?

Comment: The problem is likely not the PORT # error that you are seeing but something in the startup that is causing the container to fail to start correctly. I suggest to log at the function deployment logs and understand the root cause. The logs should point out precisely why the startup has failed. It can be due to missing dependencies, etc.

Comment: @DrewS, please let me know if the information was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error could be caused by configuration issues for the listener port which could be some mismatches in the user defined values settings.
You may check and verify the following pointers to understand the probable cause of the error and rectify these to try and  eliminate the issue:

- Check  if you configured your service to listen to all network
  interfaces,commonly denoted as 0.0.0.0 in [Troubleshooting issues](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting?&_ga=2.196286380.-1217260338.1655316723#:%7E:text=check%20if%20your%20container%20is%20listening%20on%20all%20network%20interfaces%2C%20commonly%20denoted%20as%200.0.0.0)
- Configured the PORT following [Google best practices](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#configure_container_entrypoint_command_and_arguments)
- Configured the PORT in your application as per [“Deploy a Python
  service to Cloud Run”](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service) guide.

You may check the following simple example initially to check if these are working properly.

```
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: where would this code above go? main.py?

Comment: yes, please check the official documentation link above in answer ,it will give more details about these config settings.